# Redirect blog posts to root but not blog itself

Tags: .htaccess, mod-alias

I want all the blog posts to redirect from `domain.com/blog/post-name` to `domain.com/post-name`. I added following in .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/(.*) /$1
```

This works but it also redirects `domain.com/blog/` to `domain.com/`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Try: `RedirectMatch 301 /blog/(.+) /$1`